# Checksum field in PostgreSQL to content comparison

Tags: postgresql, checksum

I have a field in a table with large content (text or binary data). If I want to know if another text is equals this one, I can use a checksum to compare the two texts. I can define this field as `UNIQUE` to avoid repeated content too.

My doubt is if I create a checksum field, this comparison will speed up, so PostgreSQL already does this (without need programmer intervention) or I need do this manually?

**EDIT:** What is better, create a checksum for a `TEXT` field, use a checksum for it or the two ways are the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no default "checksum" for large columns in PostgreSQL, you will have to implement one yourself.

#### Reply to comment

Hash indexes provide fast performance for equality checks. And they are updated automatically. But they are not fully integrated in PostgreSQL (yet), so their use is discouraged - [read the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-types.html).

And you cannot query the values and use them in your application for instance. You could do that with a checksum column, but you need to add an index for performance if your table is big and maintain the column. I would use a trigger `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` for that.

So, a hash index may or may not be for you. @A.H.'s idea certainly fits the problem ...

Comment: Ok, but if I create a checksum for a `TEXT` column or use some PostgreSQL index, the two ways will be the same thing?

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição: It depends. I added some considerations to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will do a manual checksum validation because I will need to use this values inside application too and not only in the database. I will try the two ways and see whats performs better.

Answer (score 1):

You might read the [Indexes Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/indexes-types.html) manual, because basically you want to do the same as a hash-index but with your bare hands. So you might read up on the pros and cons of a hash index in PostgreSQL.